# Query optimizer not using an index

Tags: mysql, performance, indexing

I have two tables CUSTOMER_ORDER_PUBLIC and LINEITEM_PUBLIC which have the following indices:

```
+-----------------------+------------+---------------+--------------+---------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table                 | Non_unique | Key_name      | Seq_in_index | Column_name   | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+-----------------------+------------+---------------+--------------+---------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| CUSTOMER_ORDER_PUBLIC |          1 | O_ORDERKEY    |            1 | O_ORDERKEY    | A         |     2633457 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| CUSTOMER_ORDER_PUBLIC |          1 | O_ORDERDATE   |            1 | O_ORDERDATE   | A         |        2350 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| CUSTOMER_ORDER_PUBLIC |          1 | PUB_C_CUSTKEY |            1 | PUB_C_CUSTKEY | A         |      273000 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
+-----------------------+------------+---------------+--------------+---------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
```

and:

```
+-----------------+------------+----------------------+--------------+------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table           | Non_unique | Key_name             | Seq_in_index | Column_name      | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+-----------------+------------+----------------------+--------------+------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| LINEITEM_PUBLIC |          0 | PRIMARY              |            1 | PUB_L_ORDERKEY   | A         |    16488602 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| LINEITEM_PUBLIC |          0 | PRIMARY              |            2 | PUB_L_LINENUMBER | A         |    44146904 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| LINEITEM_PUBLIC |          1 | LINEITEM_PRIVATE_FK2 |            1 | PUB_L_PARTKEY    | A         |     2083757 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| LINEITEM_PUBLIC |          1 | LINEITEM_PRIVATE_FK3 |            1 | PUB_L_SUPPKEY    | A         |       85599 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
+-----------------+------------+----------------------+--------------+------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
```

Each time I run an Explain of a specific query I get the following:

```
mysql> EXPLAIN SELECT *
    FROM CUSTOMER_ORDER_PUBLIC
    LEFT OUTER JOIN LINEITEM_PUBLIC  ON O_ORDERKEY= PUB_L_ORDERKEY;
+----+-------------+-----------------------+------------+------+---------------+---------+---------+---------------------------------------+---------+----------+-------+
| id | select_type | table                 | partitions | type | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref                                   | rows    | filtered | Extra |
+----+-------------+-----------------------+------------+------+---------------+---------+---------+---------------------------------------+---------+----------+-------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | CUSTOMER_ORDER_PUBLIC | NULL       | ALL  | NULL          | NULL    | NULL    | NULL                                  | 2900769 |   100.00 | NULL  |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | LINEITEM_PUBLIC       | NULL       | ref  | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 4       | TPCH.CUSTOMER_ORDER_PUBLIC.O_ORDERKEY |       2 |   100.00 | NULL  |
+----+-------------+-----------------------+------------+------+---------------+---------+---------+---------------------------------------+---------+----------+-------+
```

For some reason the query optimizer is not using the index (O_ORDERKEY) even if I use a FORCE INDEX. I know a lot of people posted similar questions but I tried everything and nothing seems to help!

Any other suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

**Edit:**
 The query used is the following:

```
SELECT * FROM CUSTOMER_ORDER_PUBLIC
    LEFT OUTER JOIN LINEITEM_PUBLIC  ON O_ORDERKEY= PUB_L_ORDERKEY;
```

Comment: Can you also include the query?  Note that if you are joining `CUSTOMER_ORDER_PUBLIC` to `LINEITEM_PUBLIC` then a full table scan on the former would be needed even if an index be used in the join.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen SELECT * FROM CUSTOMER_ORDER_PUBLIC LEFT OUTER JOIN LINEITEM_PUBLIC ON O_ORDERKEY= PUB_L_ORDERKEY;

Comment: @Maya:  please *edit* the question to include additional information; do not post that as a comment to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM CUSTOMER_ORDER_PUBLIC cop LEFT OUTER JOIN
     LINEITEM_PUBLIC lp
     ON cop.O_ORDERKEY = lp.PUB_L_ORDERKEY;
```

For this query, you want an index on `LINEITEM_PUBLIC(PUB_L_ORDERKEY)`.  Of course, you already have this index because this is the first key in the primary key.

There is no reason to use an index on `CUSTOMER_ORDER_PUBLIC`, because all rows in the table are going to the result set.

Comment: To add to what Gordon said, MySQL has to do a full table scan of `CUSTOMER_ORDER_PUBLIC` during the join +1

Answer (score 1):

The `FORCE INDEX` hint tells the optimizer that a full scan of the table is very expensive.

The most likely explanation for the observed behavior is that the optimizer thinks it needs to access every row in the table, and the index suggested in the hint is *not* a covering index for the query.

Based on the EXPLAIN output, we only see evidence of a single predicate on the JOIN operation. And it looks like the optimizer is choosing `CUSTOMER_ORDER_PUBLIC` as the driving table for the join, and using an index on the `LINEITEM_PUBLIC` table.

I'm not sure any of that answers the question you asked. (I'm not sure that there was a question asked.)  Absent an actual SQL statement, we are just making guesses.

I have a question: Aside from the `FORCE INDEX` hint, why would we expect the optimizer to use a particular index? And why would that be a reasonable expectation?

Comment: Thanks @spencer7593! As @Gordon Linoff pointed out, I think a scan of the full table is required since it's a left outer join. I totally missed that part. Thanks for your answer though!

Comment: Some queries could be satisfied from a full scan of a *covering* index, without any lookups to data pages in the underlying table. e.g. `SELECT o.O_ORDERKEY, l.* FROM CUSTOMER_ORDER_PUBLIC o LEFT JOIN LINEITEM_PUBLIC l ON l.PUB_L_ORDERKEY = o.O_ORDERKEY`.  In this case, the optimizer *could* make use of an index on the `O_ORDERKEY` column,

Comment: @Maya - No.  `LEFT OUTER JOIN` is not causing the full table scan.  The fact that you are not  filtering on anything (via `WHERE`) means that you _want_ all of one of the tables.  `LEFT` says it is all of the _left_ table, but then for _each_ of those rows, check the _right_ table!